# Is it possible to load/create database in sdcard using phoneGap in Android?

Tags: java, android, cordova

How can I load existing .db file from sdcard or create database in sdcard using phoneGap or any plugin that will work with phoneGap?

I want to save my .db file in sdcard because size of database might increase.

Comment: Exact problem I am facing. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I could not find any solution

Comment: Thanks. Also, ignore my reply about persistanceJS: persistanceJS doesn't work for sqlite databases on SD card, it works for webSQL databases. Voted to delete the reply.

Comment: Added an issue in Phonegap JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1191

Answer (score 4):

Same problem I am facing, but after a long thorough reading over phonegap-cordova library, I found its lacking to provide the flexibility for selecting path.

Reason may be because of cross platform limitation, library bound you to use the default app path so on different platform, library could get the file easily.

but what!! there is a trick to achieve the target ....

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
}
```

actually when JavaScript call the 'openDatabase()' function, its do following things

- add **'/data/data/< package_name_of_your_app>/'** before db_name
- and add **'.db'** after db_name

i.e : in above case resultant will be;

> /data/data/< package_name_of_your_app>/test.db

so the trick goes here;

```
function onDeviceReady() {
      var db = window.openDatabase("../../../../mnt/sdcard/test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
}
```

- add '../../../../mnt/sdcard/' before db_name, don't add extension since library add '.db' itself, if you add any extension then your db file will be **db_name.(yourextension).db**

now what! it will;

- add **'/data/data/< package_name_of_your_app>/'** before db_name
- and add **'.db'** after db_name
- it will take your db_name '../../../../mnt/sdcard/test'

therefore, resultant will be;

> /data/data/< package_name_of_your_app>/../../../../mnt/sdcard/test.db

so, it will back to root of your mobile and then **/mnt/sdcard**

Comment: This could also achieve by making own plugin,     

< plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>

Comment: '../../../../' use 4 times, dont forget to use 'mnt/sdcard', i have tried and works fine....

Comment: i am very new to phonegap and looking for creating database on sdcard. when i tried above trick i am facing a error "result of an expression 'db' [null] is not an object. can u say what's the problem?. thanks:)

Comment: Ooh Thanx @smkrn110 i have successfully saved file in my sdcard . but when i am going to retrieve it it display nothing ? is there any other way to access it

Comment: @chhameed since your db file is created successfully, the **'db'** variable is pointing to your db-file i.e already accessing, you have to review your code. Take help from [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: @smkrn110: thanks for reply .. i already resolved my issue ... :)
You are the bit late

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. along with the changes you need to mention the DB file path in your connection string. for more like code reference have a look [here](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=save-database-to-sdcard-android)

Comment: thanks for ur reply. above link given by you has code to import and export the db file from sdcard to internal memory and vice versa but i only want to use existing database kept at sdcard using phoneGap api. and my problem is that this method as given     window.openDatabase(database_name, database_version,  database_displayname, database_size); accept only database name not path that from where to load the database.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: i am using .db file, using phoneGap api when we call openDatabase() method as given above in comment. it creates two file i.e 0000000000000001.db and Databases.db so what i did is that i created these two file myself manually filled with data and now i want to keep these file at sdcard and access it using openDatabase method .

Comment: okay, i am not specialize over android so at my best i can suggest to install DB settings at card or edit the the path which is creating your 0000000000000001.db and Databases.db files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . You can,
I will just provide the link ,
http://gauravstomar.blogspot.se/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

This is actually about pre populating . You can get something from this. For someone who want to pre-populate this is what it is.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but link given by you, i have already used it, in this link db file is being pasted at phoneGap`s default database location i.e. /data/data/applicationPackageName/app_databases and loaded from here but i want to keep db files at sdcard and load from there.